# TF2 shuts down Ubuntu 16.04 randomly

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, steam

The skinny of the question is as-follows:
One Minute, i'm playing TF2, second, my computer randomly shuts down. The thing is, my computer is more than capable of running it, and the logs aren't very helpful for the messages around shutdown time.

```
Apr 16 16:00:37 UbuntuMaxorNova ureadahead[246]: ureadahead:/var/opt/mssql/.system/profiles/Temp/c01f3bb58aa10ad118dec4ee5fe53c00: No such file or directory
```

Apr 16 16:00:37 UbuntuMaxorNova ureadahead[246]: ureadahead:/var/opt/mssql/.system/profiles/Temp/e63006f33d15b1a534d7e1de3c4fac3a: No such file or directory
Apr 16 16:00:37 UbuntuMaxorNova ureadahead[246]: ureadahead:/var/opt/mssql/.system/profiles/Temp/662e67b9211376b497372fba8f4ff27a: No such file or directory
Apr 16 16:00:37 UbuntuMaxorNova ureadahead[246]: ureadahead:/var/opt/mssql/.system/profiles/Temp/32bafbd7ad466c187491263f94be1159: No such file or directory
Apr 16 16:00:37 UbuntuMaxorNova ureadahead[246]: ureadahead:/var/opt/mssql/.system/profiles/Temp/eb809a247d0e9b67fa944352b3879965: No such file or directory
Apr 16 16:00:37 UbuntuMaxorNova ureadahead[246]: ureadahead:/var/opt/mssql/.system/profiles/Temp/35c7bdc99fe6c2c6fb9083ddc8d8c071: No such file or directory
Apr 16 16:00:37 UbuntuMaxorNova ureadahead[246]: ureadahead:/var/opt/mssql/.system/profiles/Temp/8173c72ee34f5a63d0fa22157d03bba: No such file or directory
Apr 16 16:00:37 UbuntuMaxorNova ureadahead[246]: ureadahead:/var/opt/mssql/.system/profiles/Temp/5b57c3c780857c896f99e906676fa88b: No such file or directory
Apr 16 16:00:37 UbuntuMaxorNova ureadahead[246]: ureadahead:/var/opt/mssql/.system/profiles/Temp/b0bc58302e28c2f6e78a0588710e4ae5: No such file or directory
Apr 16 16:00:37 UbuntuMaxorNova ureadahead[246]: ureadahead:/var/opt/mssql/.system/profiles/Temp/c518c2ee6e7d0d558371a127651403fa: No such file or directory
Apr 16 16:00:37 UbuntuMaxorNova ureadahead[246]: ureadahead:/var/opt/mssql/.system/profiles/Temp/1fd7608261891c8b86ac6cc5f63086f: No such file or directory
Apr 16 16:00:37 UbuntuMaxorNova ureadahead[246]: ureadahead:/var/opt/mssql/.system/profiles/Temp/291a6b7653f792db42aef04cbf95e35: No such file or directory
Apr 16 16:00:37 UbuntuMaxorNova ureadahead[246]: ureadahead:/var/opt/mssql/.system/profiles/Temp/b97751e0c69ee03140c90c724106e68: No such file or directory
Apr 16 16:00:37 UbuntuMaxorNova ureadahead[246]: ureadahead:/var/opt/mssql/.system/profiles/Temp/77cfbe30595d0dc32a1a7e5d7b473140: No such file or directory
Apr 16 16:00:37 UbuntuMaxorNova ureadahead[246]: ureadahead:/var/opt/mssql/.system/profiles/Temp/6002316355d3d5dedf414aa23807bc19: No such file or directory
Apr 16 16:00:37 UbuntuMaxorNova ureadahead[246]: ureadahead:/var/opt/mssql/.system/profiles/Temp/79ecf0c911b4f07113a32172ce53641: No such file or directory
Apr 16 16:00:37 UbuntuMaxorNova ureadahead[246]: ureadahead:/var/opt/mssql/.system/profiles/Temp/e3c4dd4190456c2def93e7acb2e3be: No such file or directory
Apr 16 16:00:37 UbuntuMaxorNova ureadahead[246]: ureadahead:/var/opt/mssql/.system/profiles/Temp/8ec26a0cdfa0657a65619687fe565c2: No such file or directory
Apr 16 16:00:37 UbuntuMaxorNova ureadahead[246]: ureadahead:/var/opt/mssql/.system/profiles/Temp/279e8766cbc18ddd4aa32cdc5c89b91f: No such file or directory
Apr 16 16:00:37 UbuntuMaxorNova ureadahead[246]: ureadahead:/var/opt/mssql/.system/profiles/Temp/f4abda2806d2019c271030108bd5e7: No such file or directory
Apr 16 16:00:37 UbuntuMaxorNova ureadahead[246]: ureadahead:/var/opt/mssql/.system/profiles/Temp/368e5c8150e5746ede85b434e73d1e22: No such file or directory

This was around the shutdown time and what I got from /var/log/syslog

How can i fix this?

Also, Specs:

```
Samsung Series 3 Model Num: np305e5a-s04ca
RAM: 6GB
GPU: Gallium 0.4 On AMD SUMO (DRM 2.43.0 / 4.4.0-72-generic, LLVM 4.0.0)
OS: 64Bit
Disk Space: 624.2GB
```

EDIT: this problem happened again, so i cut out a chunk of what may be error messages from var/log/syslog.